# I am unable to use group by in nested query of ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am facing problem in using nested queries in MS access. Those queries are working  fine in sql developer.

Access SQL:-

```
select 
  B.prDate,
  B.Month, 
  (select C.Entity_Id,avg(C.prclose) 
   from **B** as C 
   where C.Month>=B.Month 
     and C.Month <= B.Month+3 
   group by C.Entity_Id)
from (
  select  A.Entity_Id, A.prDate, A.prclose , 
   (
    (SELECT max(ID) 
     FROM sheet1 where  Entity_Id=A.Entity_Id 
    ) - 
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM sheet1 where  ID=A.Id) +1
   ) as  Month  
  from sheet1 as A 
  order by Month, A.Entity_Id asc
) B
```

Or

you can replace above alias with below query

```
select B.prDate, B.Month , ((select C.Entity_Id,avg(C.prclose) from 
(select  A.Entity_Id,A.prDate,A.prclose , ((SELECT max(ID) FROM sheet1 where  Entity_Id=A.Entity_Id ) -  (SELECT ID FROM sheet1 where  ID=A.Id ) +1) as  Month  from sheet1 as A order by Month, A.Entity_Id asc) B  as C where C.Month>=B.Month and  C.Month <= B.Month+3 group by C.Entity_Id  )) 

from 

(select  A.Entity_Id,A.prDate,A.prclose , ((SELECT max(ID) FROM sheet1 where  Entity_Id=A.Entity_Id ) -  (SELECT ID FROM sheet1 where  ID=A.Id ) +1) as  Month  from sheet1 as A order by Month, A.Entity_Id asc) B
```

Other SQL:-

```
select B.prDate, B.Month , (select C.Entity_Id,avg(C.prclose) from B) as C where C.Month>=B.Month and  C.Month <= B.Month+3 group by C.Entity_Id   from  
(select  A.Entity_Id,A.prDate,A.prclose , ((SELECT max(ID) FROM sheet1 where  Entity_Id=A.Entity_Id ) -  (SELECT ID FROM sheet1 where  ID=A.Id ) +1) as  Month  from sheet1 as A order by Month, A.Entity_Id asc) B
```

Comment: Which are working and which are not working?  How are they not working -- are you getting different results?  Are you getting an error message?  We need more details -- as it stands this is a statement with some facts -- we need them all to solve.

Comment: I also formatted the first as an example of how to format to make your code readable -- do you see how this is clearer?  When sharing with others this makes a big difference.

Comment: After formatting I can see the line `order by Month, A.Entity_Id asc` has no logical value.  I'd suggest removing that line.

Comment: Order by I had used to see data in proper order only I will remove it. I had made above queries to access same resultset but got failed

Answer (score 0):

In `SELECT` clause subqueries, you cannot return more than one field as you attempt with aggregate query. To resolve, because you need to reuse *B*, consider saving this resultset in an intermediate, external query and reference it in a final query:

**Intermediate Query** *(save as MS Access query object; last nested `SELECT` is redundant)*

```
SELECT A.Entity_Id, A.prDate, A.prclose, 
       ((SELECT MAX(sub.ID) 
         FROM sheet1 sub
         WHERE sub.Entity_Id = A.Entity_Id) - sub.ID) + 1 AS [Month]
FROM sheet1 as A
```

**Final Query**

```
SELECT q.Entity_Id, q.prDate, q.[Month],
       (SELECT AVG(sub_q.prclose)
        FROM mySavedQuery AS sub_q
        WHERE sub_q.Entity_Id = q.Entity_Id
          AND sub_q.[Month] >= q.[Month] 
          AND sub_q.[Month] <= q.[Month] + 3 
       ) AS Avg_PrClose
FROM mySavedQuery AS q
ORDER BY q.[Month], q.Entity_Id
```

---

When the day comes when MS Access SQL supports CTE (or you upsize to an enterprise RDBMS), you can turn the saved query object into `WITH` clause for one statement:

```
WITH mySavedQuery AS
  (SELECT A.Entity_Id, A.prDate, A.prclose, 
          ((SELECT MAX(sub.ID) 
            FROM sheet1 sub
            WHERE sub.Entity_Id = A.Entity_Id) - sub.ID) + 1 AS [Month]
   FROM sheet1 as A)

SELECT q.Entity_Id, q.prDate, q.[Month],
       (SELECT AVG(sub_q.prclose)
        FROM mySavedQuery AS sub_q
        WHERE sub_q.Entity_Id = q.Entity_Id
          AND sub_q.[Month] >= q.[Month] 
          AND sub_q.[Month] <= q.[Month] + 3 
       ) AS Avg_PrClose
FROM mySavedQuery AS q
ORDER BY q.[Month], q.Entity_Id
```

Comment: agg_q.[Month] object is not avaialble in the agg_q

Comment: See edit. You will need a correlated subquery (not as efficient as `JOIN`) for the rolling windows by *Month*.